# Filtering one table by values from another table in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to filter the first table by the second table- is this as easy as an inner join?

```
select * from 
table_a A
inner join table_b B on (A.mer_no=B.se_no)
```

Table A:

```
mer_no  Country  Account Name
1234    USA      Dunkin
3456    India    Pizza Hut
6789    UK       Thomas Bagels
```

Table B:

```
se_no
3456
6789
```

Comment: Did you test it?   Assuming se_no from Table B is the same as the mer_no in Table A, then yes, you've got it right.

Comment: Assuming there are no duplicates and you want to filter out `NULL` values, then "yes".

Answer (score 0):

This will output:

```
3456    India    Pizza Hut      3456
6789    UK       Thomas Bagels  6789
```